# Android Material Design Bottom Navigation and Drawer combined

Tags: android, xamarin.android, material-design

I'm wondering if I should combine the material design Bottom Navigation and the Navigation Drawer.

As is understand there is always one item active in the Bottom Navigation Bar, but what if I choose to navigate to a page using the Navigation Drawer menu? How do I preserve navigation consistency.? The Bottom Navigation item will still be active even if I navigated to a different activity/fragment.

I was thinking about setting all Bottom Navigation items to inactive in case a user navigates using the Navigation Drawer.
Unfortunately, the lib I'm using (https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar) doesn't support this.

How does the Bottom Nav Bar coexist with the Navigation Drawer? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#), it's pretty clear that the navigation drawer is at a higher z-level (hence higher hierarchy). Think of bottom navigation as essentially a replacement for tab layouts. You can look at the Google Photos application as an example.

Comment: oh yeah, thanks for the hint! that makes sense! the google photos app shows it pretty clear